# Randomly errors for insert and select data

Tags: google-bigquery

In the last couple of weeks we are getting a lot of the following errors:
{"code":503,"message":null}

And those errors too:
"insertErrors":[{"index":23,"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}]},{"index":74,"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}]},{"index":79,"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}]}]

The rows are randomly failed to insert, when we try to insert them again it works fine, which mean there is no problem with the data we are sending.

For me it looks like you have problems with couple of shards that holds the data and execute the tasks.

** If you have any stability problems please notify in advance.

About the two of the above mentioned errors, I tried the suggestions you wrote for other users, about retry, send small chunk of data, etc.. nothing help.

Any other solutions?

Meir.

Comment: Read my post on, possible duplicate  [Google BigQuery: Slow streaming inserts performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916985/google-bigquery-slow-streaming-inserts-performance)

Comment: Hi, I'm a representative of Google Cloud Platform. As you may observe in https://status.cloud.google.com/ there were no issues for BigQuery in the last days. The suggestions from @Pentium10 about exponential back-off is exactly the recommended way to tackle those issues, unless you would be exceeding your quota. After implementing exponential back-off, are you still suffering those errors?