# Random Timeout/Connection Errors with Google Bigquery Streaming Inserts

Tags: google-bigquery, sidekiq

We have started evaluating Bigquery's streaming insert feature for High volume event logging . currently, we are running test workloads in production ENV. 
[image]

As soon we went live with this solution, we got Following error:
"*Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem*."

After reading about it in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors), It seems the recommended way of is to use queue based system. so we moved to a [sidekiq & redis](http://sidekiq.org/) which has retry with exponential backoff.here we spinup a new worker thread every 1 second or when the batch size reaches 1MB (one megabyte), whichever occurs first

Now,
we are getting 2 errors:

1. `Network TimeoutError`, We retry them after specifying the [`insertID`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) for each row but docs says that only de-dups for 1min but with a exponential backoff, it we could still end up inserting duplicate records in the database which is okay but less than ideal.
2. `Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "www.googleapis.com" port 443`

Upon these errors, we retry with exponential backoff but I would like to know why error occurs & how can we minimize them

Comment: As I see from your enclosed image, the error rate is extremely low. Are you sure your errors are not a result of your own infrastructure routing failure? As it seams the errors are not reaching BQ counts. Read my recommendations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916985/google-bigquery-slow-streaming-inserts-performance/26918042#26918042

Comment: No, nothing else is affected. so doesn't seem like network issue. we open a new connection to BQ API on every thread as processing happen in a queue. could that be the reason?

Comment: It could be something lower, did you checked your Linux limits? Maybe open files? Or large connections on TIME_WAIT? The SSL handshake might be broken because of wrong synced clock etc...

Comment: Any issue that doesn't fit the 99.95% uptime rate is really unusual, thus it should be visible at others, our projects run smoothly so there might not be a permanent issue.

Comment: Try setting up a simple script that only keeps inserting a dummy simple row into some table, maybe do that script in other language that you currently have, often the libraries have some issues with their own connection pooling/thread managements.

Comment: Couple of questions/comments:

1) What are your observed error rates? From the graph above it looks like ~1/100,000 requests? Is that what you're actually seeing? 2) The duplicate removal window is on the order of minutes. Assuming you're doing something like immediate retry, .5 second delay, 1 second delay, 2 second, etc (ideally with some jittering factor), you can be fairly confident in a successful attempt within the duplicate removal window. Are you seeing multiple successive retry attempts fail? 3) If you provide us with a project id, we can check if there are problem specific to you.

Comment: 1. 2 x "Internal Error". 2 x "Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem." 4 x "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed." 24 x "TimeoutError". 2. we retry failures with an exponential backoff using the formula (retry_count ** 4) + 15 + (rand(30) * (retry_count + 1)) (i.e. 15, 16, 31, 96, 271, ... seconds + a random amount of time). It will perform 25 retries over approximately 21 days, hence I am sure there will be duplicates. Project ID: circular-gist-812, analytics_demo.email_events

Comment: @Pentium10 WE run workers on AWS's t2.medium on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  open file limit is 65,536 & clocks are synced using NTP. How do setup monitoring for  "TIME_WAIT" connections?

Comment: The numbers you say above are pretty normal error rates. I think this is functioning at normal parameters. You cannot expect 100% success. Also your retries solve the problem. The problem could be when you try with retry and you cannot send the data to BQ. If that's the problem, maybe try locating the row, and actually provide a sequence of issues that hit the same streaming row, but I can't imagine that would be a problem. I think here the situation is that you need to accept the SLA uptime rate is 99.95%.