# bigquery-api-go-client, bigquery streaming inserts latency

Tags: go, google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-client

Is there an optimal way to improve the speed of requests to an insertAll request via the golang client?

My current structure is such that:

1. Rows get submit to a queue
2. Upon hitting job size, a new job is queued up (approx. 250 rows)
3. A worker picks up a job from the queue
4. Worker formats + sends insertAll request to BQ

The above works fairly well, however I seem to be having an average of 8-12 seconds per 250 row request.

I should mention that the number of workers being used is generally 200, however I have tried higher / lower values and it does not seem to make much a difference (higher usually seems to take longer per job).

Comment: That's way to much, we see sub 2 second times, see my notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916985/google-bigquery-slow-streaming-inserts-performance/26918042#26918042

Comment: @Pentium10 when you say way to much, do you mean in terms of workers or in terms of time per job? I have read your post previously while looking for similar problems.

Edit: seemingly lowering the number of workers does decrease latency however It cannot keep up with the amount of work coming in.

Comment: It would seem that finding the right amount of concurrency is going to be key here, I currently can't seem to use more than 4 MB/s of bandwidth when submitting streaming inserts - I will continue to tweak and post findings

Comment: consider using https://github.com/rounds/go-bqstreamer (Go streaming to BigQuery)