# BigQuery InsertAll: C# API Performance Issue

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

C#:

```
 Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 TableDataInsertAllResponse response = await BigQueryService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, _account.ProjectId, table.DataSetId, tableId).ExecuteAsync(ct); 
  stopwatch2.Stop();
```

JAVA:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
TableDataInsertAllResponse response = mBigquery.tabledata().insertAll(mAccount.getProjectId(), tid.getDatasetId(),tid.getDefaultTableId(), request).execute();
logger.fatal(String.format("%s~BigQuery.InsertAll#Back~%s~%s~%s~%s",FormatHelper.getCurrentDateTime(), rowList.size(), tid,System.currentTimeMillis()-start, payLoad));
```

As we compared these two against a same dataset and same machine, C# is usually 3-5 times slower than Java call (>500ms vs ~100ms). we traced as deep as we could into the BQ API source code, and found they are basically with the same process of data: serialized data to json and then do gzip and then send out through http calls. it just does not make sense that C# http calls could be that slow. We think we need technical support from BigQuery side on our specific cases to see what happens after BQ receives our request. If any very specific payload differences lead to the performance difference.  **What level of support package do we need to get?**

**Edit**
Some add-on: Right now, our c# solution is all async (using async and await in c#). I found a post [BigQuery streaming 'insertAll' performance with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522211/bigquery-streaming-insertall-performance-with-php) for PHP. I'm having the the same problem with this post. our application cannot wait for more than 100ms for a request. We can forget about comparing it to Java, but we just need the c# calls can run more quicker. I'm wondering **if any improvement on InsertAll() or on our side can be done for c#.**

Comment: Which one are you doing first?  if its the same query you are running the data is cashed on Googles Servers for an undefined length of time the second request will be faster because its accessing cashed data.

Comment: @DalmTo  I'm not running any queries, but doing data streaming. And this is not just a test, we ran the program to streaming real-time data-flow into BQ and the comparison result is derived from from our executing log.

Comment: By Queries I meant requests sent to the API.    Have you tried digging around in the source code for the client library I wonder if something in that could be tuned.

Comment: @DalmTo as to my understanding, BQ will not be faster on streaming data that has been streamed just now or before. it's not the same with running a query to get some result. But I get what you mean. I did dig into their source code, both C# and Java API are using native http request at the end of their call. Also ,both of them will serialize data into json string, gzip the string and then send data. I am wondering if it's anything different in the request payload should be responsible for this.

Comment: You can add this as an issue on this. Net  client lib I will mark it needs research.   It could also be an issue with the JSON lib.   We will need to do some testing

Comment: @DalmTo we just upgrade our account to Gold. What could I do next? I mean, could we get designated technical assistance and we can work together on this if it helps.  One of our main project is relying on it.I want it to settle soon.

Comment: I don't know if the big query team will support the Google. Net client lib but you can try. It's an open source project

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client  that is the main project.    Big query dll is dynamic built

Comment: @DaImTo thank you. I'll try contact BigQuery team first. And I'll let you know